# PHP: run class method when another class method is run?

Tags: php, class, methods, listener

PHP:
run function when a specific class method is run

what I want is to run some additional functions when a class method is run without altering the already existing class.

how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a [decorator](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator):

```
class MyClassDecorator
{
    protected $decoratedInstance;

    public function __construct($decoratedInstance)
    {
        $this->decoratedInstance = $decoratedInstance;
    }

    public function methodNameInOriginalClass()
    {
        $this->decoratedInstance->methodIWantToRunBefore();
        $this->decoratedInstance->methodNameInOriginalClass();
        $this->decoratedInstance->methodIWantToRunAfter();
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (method_exists($this->decoratedInstance, $method)) {
            return call_user_func_array(
                array($this->decoratedInstance, $method), 
                $args
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The above assumes that the methods you want to call are `public` on the `$decoratedInstance`.

Comment: works flawlessly, thank you.

also adding this helps:
 function &__get($prop_name){
     if (isset($this->originalClass->$prop_name)) {
      return $this->originalClass->$prop_name;
     } else {
      return false;
     }
 }

:P

Comment: Absolutely yes, but for brevity's sake I skipped it.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, you will have to alter the function to achieve that. But you might be in need of an [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (The zend guys describe the [observer pattern on zend.com](http://devzone.zend.com/article/5), too)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to extend the original class and override the method adding your code.

```
class MyClass extends OriginalClass
{
    public function originalMethod()
    {
        parent::originalMethod();

        // My code...
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->originalMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Currently PHP has not support for that out of the box, although you can use extensions. Here is post that explains some of the options: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/573-Current-State-of-AOP-for-PHP.html

Answer (score 1):

- [runkit](http://pecl.php.net/package/runkit): Replace, rename, and remove user defined functions and classes.
- [funcall](http://pecl.php.net/package/funcall): Call callbacks before or after specified functions/methods being called.
- [intercept](http://pecl.php.net/package/intercept): Allows the user to have a user-space function called when the specified function or method is called.

not that using these is necessarily a good idea.